# How to pass the input file type to ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC using ajax with traditional?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How to pass the input file type to ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC using ajax with traditional below?

```
const _f = JSON.stringify({
                    data: {
                        users_pid : xusers_pid,
                        avatar: {
                            file: document.getElementById('avatar_logo').files[0]
                        }
                    }
                });
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  '/User/Update/',
                    traditional: true,
                    data: _f,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        showSuccess(result.message);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        showError(result.message);
                    }
                });

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/User/Update")]
    public JsonResult Update_Data([FromBody] JObject _jo)
    {  }
```

I don't know how to pass the value of input file type (in my case is avatar_logo) to ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a file to action with ajax,you can try to use `FormData`.Here is a working demo:

Models:

```
public class FileModel{
        public string users_pid { get; set; }
        public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
    }
    public class Avatar {
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<input id="theFile" type="file" />
<input id="xusers_pid" />
<button onclick="PostFile()">
    submit
</button>
```

js:

```
function PostFile() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('avatar.file', $('#theFile').get(0).files[0]);
        formData.append('users_pid', $("#xusers_pid").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/User/Update/",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
            }

        });
    }
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("/User/Update")]
        public JsonResult Update_Data(FileModel fileModel)
        {
            return new JsonResult("s");
        }
```

result:
[image]